# Rails fields_for won't see my field inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am trying to create two object at the same time. The best approach I have is to used fields_for. and the relationship is has_many.

model/location.rb

```
  attr_accessible :address, :customer_id, :event_id, :latitude, :longitude
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :event
```

model/event.rb

```
  attr_accessible :locations_attributes
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
```

The form is has follow:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :locations do |e| %>
    <%= e.text_field :longitude %>
    <%= e.text_field :latitude %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My fields won't show up, I have followed the documentation has_many from this section http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for
and notice if in my f.fields_for :locations change it to singular than the fields will show up but i won't be able to create it because i am not allow to modify the locations_attributes.

UPDATE:

If i singular it. I change this to my event model

```
  attr_accessible  :description, :title, :location_attributes
```

The error is like this

```
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:60:in `new'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:60:in `create'
```

My controller is like this

```
line 60: @event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

Comment: As you said, it should be `<%= f.fields_for :location do |e| %>` not `:locations` why can't you fix it ?

Comment: Cause i get an error can't mass_assignment, if i look at the document it also states to have it plurials

Comment: add location_attributes to model

Comment: I just try and get this error still Can't mass-assign protected attributes: location. I updated something

Comment: Updated what Khaled said????

Comment: The code, to showcase my issues, i think my controller is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this in your form: (location not locations)

```
<%= f.fields_for :location do |e| %>
    <%= e.text_field :longitude %>
    <%= e.text_field :latitude %>
<% end %>
```

and in your model event.rb

`attr_accessible  :description, :title, :locations_attributes` (locations not location)